# Windows Touchscreen drivers not working properly

Tags: windows-10, drivers, windows-update, touchscreen, windows-tabletpc

I'm currently using Windows 10 on a tablet/PC, the touch screen feature used to work flawlessly on the original install of Windows 10 which came with the device. But after I tried to install Ubuntu I couldn't login on Windows anymore and had to make a fresh install, but now the driver doesn't work properly anymore with the screen touch commands mirrored, apparently divided in half and the cursor moving on the opposite direction of my finger. I tried to install the drivers from the Windows update catalogue and the ones made available by the manufacturer, but the screen behave even more strangely or no change was perceived. I think the device is a Silead Touch L2c.

- Is there a way to check the device (Touchscreen) model on my machine?
- What is the correct way to install a driver having the *.sys and *.fw files.
- Can You think of any possible solution? The manufacturer offered to collect my device for technical assistance, but I can't allow being without my device at the moment.

Comment: Hi, please check if the method in this article was helpful: [What to try if your touchscreen doesn't work](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/what-to-try-if-your-touchscreen-doesn-t-work-f159b366-b3ef-99ad-24a4-31a4c62ab46d)

Comment: @SunnyQi I have a similar problem, touchscreen works fine before windows boots up (e.g. for preboot warnings), updating and restarting doesn't solve the issue. And it showes up fine in the Devicemanager as `HID-konform Touchscreen` (translated from German)

Comment: @Andre did you check the device manager? There should be s.th. under `Inputdevices` called `HID-konform Touchscreen`

Comment: Hi, @SunnyQi. I don't think that solution applies because my device is not a surface book and I had my Windows up to date trying to solve the problem, but saw no difference.

Comment: Hello, @Albin. Actually there's no HID-konform Touchscreen on the device manager, couldn't locate input devices either. There's only "Touchscreen Compatible with HID" under "Human Interface Devices" toggle menu.

Comment: @andre check if this a the correct entry for your make and model (including driver name and version). You might need a different driver.

Comment: @Albin, unfortunately I don't know how to do that, I searched on the Windows update catalogue for this device and the results were rather limited and dated form 2015, 2016 or before.

Comment: The device manager will show you the driver details for the device

Comment: When I click in driver details it says that "It was not necessary or no driver files were loaded for this device."

Comment: Every HW-Device must have a driver, at least some generic MS driver. In this case I would suspect that this is you problem, check with your manufacturer which driver can be used.

Comment: I don't know, when I try to install the ones made available for a similar product (only to 2GB ram less) it says that the devcon failed, some tutorials tells to paste the *.sys and .fw files on drivers folder inside System32 using Linux. I did it, but since I don't know for sure which files to use, the touch kept the strange behavior.

Comment: just contact the manufacturer